# What is equivalent of isNullOrEmpty in Postgresql select command?

Tags: postgresql

```
select complaintno from complaintprocess  where endtime='';
```

It Is Not Working

In `complaintprocess` table `endtime` datatype is `timestamp` without time zone.
 Here I want to get one of the column in `complaintprocess` where `endtime` is empty.

Comment: `''` is a string literal. Comparing strings to timestamps doesn't make sense. Use `where endtime is null` to check for the absence of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not store `''` as timestamp. I suspect that by `blank` you mean `NULL` value.

```
SELECT CAST('' AS timestamp);
-- ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
```

To filter them you could use:

```
SELECT complaintno 
FROM complaintprocess  
WHERE endtime IS NULL;
```